# Flutter - Navigate in PopupMenuButton onTap does not work

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I used to use IconButton's *onpressed* to navigate to the settings page from my AppBar which worked.
Now I am trying to trigger the navigation from a PopupMenuItem's *onTap* but the page does not navigate. Both widgets are in the same hierarchy and I can't find out the reason for the different behavior. No error is thrown.

Here is the code of my appBar which contains the actions:

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext ctx) {
    return Container(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('MyApp'),
          actions: [
            PopupMenuButton(
              itemBuilder: (context) => [
// THE NAVIGATION IN onTap DOES NOT WORK
                PopupMenuItem(
                  child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).settings),
                  onTap: () => _openSettings(ctx),
                ),
              ],
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.settings,
              ),
            ),
// THIS WORKS
            IconButton(onPressed: () => _openSettings(ctx), 
                            icon: Icon(Icons.settings))
          ],
        ),
        body: Text("")  
      ),
    );
  }
```

And here the function whose navigation call only works inside IconButton's *onpressed*.
I could confirm that the function was triggered in both cases though:

```dart
  Future<void> _openSettings(BuildContext ctx) async {
    print('settings');
    await  Navigator.push(
        ctx, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctx) => SettingsPage()));
    print('settings completed');
  }
```

I'd appreciate any help!

**Workaround:**
I have not found out what the issue with *onTap* navigation is but now I am just using *onSelected* which results in the same UX and works:

```
Widget build(BuildContext ctx) {
    return Container(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('MyApp'),
          actions: [
            PopupMenuButton(
              onSelected: (result){
                switch(result){
                  case 0: _openSettings(); break;
                  case 1: _signOut(); break;
                }
              },
              itemBuilder: (context) => [
                PopupMenuItem(
                  child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).settings),
                value: 0
                ),
                PopupMenuItem(
                  child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).logout),
                  value: 1
                )
              ],
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.settings,
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
      )
    );
 }
```

Comment: Can you try passing the `context` from the `itemBuilder` into `_openSettings()`? So you can pass the correct `context` to the Navigator

Answer (score 6):

I also faced this problem and solved it as follows:

1. First you must remove `onTap` or make its value `null`.
2. Second, give a value to the `value` parameter in `PopupMenuItem`. You can give any type like `int` or `String` or whatever you want since value is dynamic.
3. then, pass a function to the `onSelected` parameter in the `PopupMenuButton`.
4. Inside the `onSelected` function you can choose what you want to do when any of the menu items is pressed.

In your case, your code should be like this

```
  PopupMenuButton(
    itemBuilder: (context) => [
      PopupMenuItem(
        child: Text(...),
        value: 'settings',
      ),
    ],
    onSelected: (value){
      if(value == 'settings'){
        _openSettings(ctx);
      }
    },
  ),
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue (except: I am using GetX for Navigation.

I think this happens because flutter is closing the PopupMenuButton automatically and because navigation happens to fast, it closes the new route instead of the menuButton.

I solved it like this in the navigating method:

```
void edit() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 10));
  Get.toNamed('/new/route'); // same like Navigator.of(context).pushNamed()
}
```

It's not beautiful... i know. But it works XD

Comment: I just figured out that its already enough to await 1 millisecond

Comment: This one worked for me. I am calling the navigation in the `onTap:` function and of course, I am only delaying for 1 millisecond.

Answer (score 1):

you need to invoke the future function using `()=>`, and pass `Build Context` for the function to know which context to navigate from.

so your button will change like this:

```
   IconButton(onPressed:()=> _openSettings(context), icon: Icon(Icons.settings))
```

and your function should be like this:

```
Future<void> _openSettings(BuildContext ctx) async {
    print('settings');
    await Navigator.push(
        ctx, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SettingPage()));
    print('settings completed');
  }
```

here is the entire code that I've tested the issue on:

```
class PlayGround extends StatefulWidget {
  const PlayGround({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PlayGroundState createState() => _PlayGroundState();
}

class _PlayGroundState extends State<PlayGround> {
  final _title =
      TextEditingController.fromValue(TextEditingValue(text: 'initialTitle'));

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('MyApp'),
          actions: [
            PopupMenuButton<int>(
              itemBuilder: (context) => [
                PopupMenuItem(
                  child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).settings),
                  onTap: () {},
                ),
                PopupMenuItem(
                  child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).logout),
                  onTap: () {},
                )
              ],
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.settings,
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () => _openSettings(context),
                icon: Icon(Icons.settings))
          ],
        ),
        body: Container());
  }

  Future<void> _openSettings(BuildContext ctx) async {
    print('settings');
    await Navigator.push(
        ctx, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SettingPage()));
    print('settings completed');
  }
}

class SettingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SettingPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The call from onPressed worked before already. I applied the changes you proposed to the call in PopupMenuItem but the navigation after the onTap call still does not work unfortunately.

Comment: I added the code where the issue has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me as well. The problem is when I add the _openSettings call to the PopupMenuItem (like here: PopupMenuItem(
                  child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).settings),
                  onTap: ()=>_openSettings(ctx),
                )) is does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. When the menu item is tapped, it schedules a callback to be executed after the current frame is rendered. This ensures that the navigation action (using Get.to(() => Settings());) is performed after the widget tree is fully built, which is necessary for navigation to work correctly.

```
SchedularBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_){

//your code here,
//this is executed after the first frame is rendered
});

        

PopupMenuItem(
onTap: (){
    SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
         Get.to(() => Settings());
});
```

hope it helps:)

Comment: Please avoid code only answer and provide an explanation. You also could have a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: please refer to original post for context, I think the code is quite self explanatory, but I have made edits with the explanation of how the code works and how it solves the problem in  question